# for loop in frame subtitle of beamer

Tags: beamer, foreach

I would like to build multiple slides of a frame in beamer by using a for-loop to load a specific image file out of a group in each slide.

Currently, I can either loop inside the frame and advance in slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A title}
    \framesubtitle{A subtitle}
    \foreach \i in {1,2}{% loop 
    \only<\i>{\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{pic\i.PNG}
    This is pic \i.}
    }% end of loop
\end{frame}
```

Or I can iteratively create different frames, leaving the same title but advancing the subtitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,2}{% loop 
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A title}
    \framesubtitle{A subtitle for pic \i}
    \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{pic\i.PNG}
\end{frame}
}% end of loop
\end{document}
```

The last outputs the result I am after, but it is only a workaround: frames are separate, but simply with redundant title.

When I try to loop inside the frame including only the subtitle, like below, it doesn't work:

```
\begin{frame}
   \foreach \i in {1,2}{% loop 
      \frametitle{A title}
      \framesubtitle{A subtitle for pic \i{} that doesn't increment}
      \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{pic\i.PNG}
   }% end of loop
\end{frame}
```

Any ideas how one may achieve this? The advantage of this is that one can add a brief incrementing description in the subtitle, instead of the main text, without taking space thus from the \textheight available for the image(s).

**Edit**:
Also tried defining an array and passing this as the argument, but still didn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}  % added based on Andrew's comment
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
%
\begin{document}
\newarray\myIncStr
\readarray{myIncStr}{1&2}
\begin{frame}
\foreach \i\iChar in {1/a,2/b}{% loop 
    \frametitle{A title}
    \framesubtitle<\i>{Subtitle \myIncStr(\i)}
    \only<\i>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-\iChar}
        
        \myIncStr(\i)%
    }
}% end of loop
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

The only way I succeeded in the subtitle's update was by using a counter in its argument. Note how its evaluation leads +1 the slide's main text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{acounter}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{acounter}{0}
\begin{frame}
\foreach \i\iChar in {1/a,2/b}{% loop 
    \frametitle{A title}
    \framesubtitle<\i>{Subtitle \theacounter{}} % evaluated after stepping up
    \only<\i>{%
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-\iChar}
        
        \theacounter{} 
        \stepcounter{acounter}
    }
}% end of loop
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is good enough, but the `\framesubtitle` command accepts an `<>`-argument to specify the slides. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be possible to define this inside a loop but you can set of the frame subtitles first and then load your images inside a loop:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A title}
   \framesubtitle<1>{A subtitle for pic 1 that doesn't increment}
   \framesubtitle<2>{A subtitle for pic 2 that doesn't increment}
   \foreach \img in {a,b}{% loop
      \includegraphics<\sli>[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-\img}
   }% end of loop
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

I am using images from the [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package, which is why I am looping over `a,b` instead of `1,2`. For reasons that I do not understand the following does not compile:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A title}
   \foreach \ind/\img in {1/a,2/b}{% loop
      \framesubtitle<\ind>{A subtitle for pic \ind{} that doesn't increment}
      \includegraphics<\ind>[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-\img}
   }% end of loop
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Andrew, as soon as you remove the "\ind{}" from the \framesubtitle argument your last snippet works, which points back to the redefinition of the frame titles being tricky after \begin{frame}. Thanks for the hints.